# How do I say 'unwanted pooping?'

Tags: meaning

In elderly, there are a lot of people who poop against their will.
How do I describe in conversation that situation if I have that unwanted, embarassing symptom?

Comment: You could say you are unable to control your bowel movements. The medical term is *fecal incontinence*.

Comment: There is a difference between leakage (lack of positive sphincter control) and the involuntary spasm of the sphincter. The 'rest' state of the sphincter is actually a tension, maintaining a closed passage. So involuntary relaxation causes leakage and involuntary spasm causes ejection. 'Involuntary bowel movement' covers both instances of incontinence.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the word [**incontinence**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/incontinence) defined by the Collins dictionary as

> the inability to prevent urine or faeces coming out of your body.
>
> - Incontinence is not just a condition of old age.

The Merriam-Webster dictionary describes incontinence as

> inability of the body to control the evacuative functions of urination or defecation 
>     partial or complete loss of bladder or bowel control
>
> - fecal incontinence
> - urinary incontinence — see also stress incontinence, urge incontinence

As populations continue to age, more and more elderly people need to rely on [adult diapers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adult_diaper) or [incontinence pads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incontinence_pad). Diapers is US English and nappies is UK English.